# Enable/Disable Kendo Grid Cells

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a DropDownlist and Kendo Grid. If value selected in dropdownlist is 1 the cells in the Grid should be editable, and if the selected value is 2 the cells in the grid should not be editable. The following is the code for Kendo Grid.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Data.Items)
  .Name("Grid1")
  .Columns(columns =>
       {
         columns.Bound(p => p.first).Title("first").Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).Format("{0:N}").ClientTemplate("");
         columns.Bound(p => p.second).Title("second").Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).Format("{0:N}");
         columns.Bound(p => p.third).Title("Third").Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
       })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .ServerOperation(true)
  .Model(Model=> { Model.Id(p => p.first); })

   )
  .Selectable()                                        
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
  .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(179)))
```

Using I can edit the cell at all times, but I need a condition where the cells should not be editable when dropdownlist selected value changes. (Note:Grid is in .cshtml(view) page, not in js file.)

Please help me with this.

Comment: you need to use jquery to detect select change and make your grid row editable or not according to this selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this impossible without the use of a grid `event` which calls a Javascript function.

You can use the `edit` event wired up to a function which you can use to apply conditional checks on the data:

```
function onEdit(e) {          
    if(e.model.ShipCountry == "Germany" && e.container.index() == 0) {
       this.closeCell(); 
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `onEdit` function checks if the row at the currently clicked cell has a `ShipCountry` equal to Germany and if the sender of the event is at column 0. If so, it closes the cell thereby blocking it from edit.

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EnOmO/4) to demonstrate. Take a look at the console to see the object attributes that `e` sent via the edit event and `e.model` have to offer.

Note: The example is purely Javascript, but you can wire up the `edit` event to the grid on MVC using:

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
```

Note: The function(onEdit) in .js file should be placed before $(document).ready function, because the grid renders before the document.ready() is triggered.

Comment: I have tried this, but I am getting "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'onEdit' is undefined" this error.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying in the answer that the `onEdit` function needs to be outside `document.ready`, the example does demonstrate the need for this.